# Test against webserver

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I have a C# library that interacts with webservers. (Specifically, it implements various means of binding local data to a remote source). All the webserver needs to do is return simple strings to simple HTTP requests. (Later, I'll add handling web sockets)

I would like to have a self-sufficient test suite for this library; so it seemed to me that a reasonable way to do this was to implement a simple C# web server (which so far seems delightfully simple). Tests could then start up a thread with the server, then run against it, and then shut down the server thread.

However, I'm running into difficulty. Is there a better way / more canonical to do this?

Note: Complex solutions are not going to be better.

Note2: Wrapping Web services in wrappers and stubbing those would defeat much of the purpose of the library in the first place.

Comment: This appears to be what I'm after: https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways of creating simple web servers.

I use Node.js to create Mock web servers for testing things like C# web clients. Python is another option.

If you like to stay with C# here's another simple solution, this can be adapted:
https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server

Comment: Right, but, when you do that, how do you bundle the server with the C# code and test runners?

Comment: You can deploy Node.js scripts without too much problem as part of test generation. The same would go for the C# web server, you can instantiate the test server(s) as part of integration testing.

Comment: Can you throw some more words at *how* to deploy the Node scripts as part of test generation?

Comment: Hi, well you will need Node.js installed, then you'd normally copy your .js script, e.g. web_server.js to a directory in the test environment. In addition you'll have a package.json describing the dependencies of this script. Running npm install will install those dependencies for you. Then running Node web_server.js <args> will start the process.

Comment: Hmm :/ Not exactly simple. Thanks, tho!

Comment: If you're more comfortable with C# you're probably better to go with the Simple-C-Web-Server. That approach will also work nicely. And deploying that should be the same level of difficulty as deploying your client code.